# How to use digital certificates with jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I need to sign a xml document using a token device in the client. How can i extract the private key from the token using JSF? I used to do it using an Applet.

Comment: if the token is worth anything, it won't let you have the secret...

Comment: Try in plain html and you can port that solution to jsf fairly easily.

Comment: Plain HTML? How it would help me to access the token in the client machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't use a token device on a browser for any other thing than SSL authentication.

The security restrictions of the browsers does not allow you to access the system certificate keystore or use a PKCS#11 driver so you can not make a digital signature

In the old days the browsers allowed to run applets, but now it is not possible anymore. You would need to use an external software

Comment: You mean using sofware installed in the client?

Comment: Yes, it is a common solution when you have to use resources that are not accessible from the browser.